# How to automatically stay updated with the latest mainline kernel?

Tags: kernel

Ubuntu manages a list of [mainline kernels](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D). If I wish to stay updated on a specific major revision (3.12.x), how can I automate this? And how do I stop Software Updater from suggesting 3.11.x kernels when searching for new updates.

Comment: What is the purpouse of gettins the mainline kernel? you do no get the specific ubuntu patches and are mostly for testing, not daily use.

Comment: My question was not whether it is a good idea, only how it's achievable. There could be any number of very valid reasons, really. For the purpose of this discussion, let's just say it's for improved ext4 performance and stability is dispensable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a GitHub repository that does this: https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater

1. If you haven't used git before: `sudo apt-get install git`
2. `git clone https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater.git`
3. `cd Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater`
4. `chmod +x install`
5. `./install`

Skimmed through the source, looks like it should work as advertised. Checks for updates 60 seconds after each startup. Will update here if I encounter any problems during next minor revision update.

*Edit:*

Enter `KernelUpdateChecker -h` at a terminal to see all available options.

I'm on 13.10 and would like to stay updated on 14.04's kernel versions 3.12.x (excluding release candidates), so I edited `~/.config/autostart/KernelUpdate.desktop` line 7 to read:

`Exec=sh -c 'sleep 60;KernelUpdateChecker -no-rc -r trusty -v 3.12'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move for kernel testing, get the required kernel from [Ubuntu Kernels](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D) then install it.

After installing it, open software sources and make the selection for proposed updates also.

I mean

[image]

So whenever there is a new build, you will get the update automatically.

Comment: Thanks raj! Once I confirm this on next kernel minor revision update, I'll accept the answer. Way simpler than the workaround I found (see below).

Comment: I just read up a bit more on pre-released updates. I find it disingenuous that this was described as "If you want to move for Kernel testing", when the question was regarding staying updated on 3.12.x kernel and what you described will basically cause Software Updater to upgrade EVERYTHING with unstable, pre-released software.