# How to safely update software with a non-standard kernel?

Tags: nvidia, kernel, asus

#### Background

I have an Asus UX302LA laptop running Ubuntu 14.04. As the default kernel mainline (3.13.*) is incompatible with the GeForce graphics card it ships with I switched to to a `drm-intel-nightly` kernel [as described here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1265544/comments/111) (after struggling with it for months). Although it is named `trusty` it's version is 3.15.0-994 making me suspect it was a misnamed Utopic Unicorn kernel. Later versions of the Utopic kernels are also [confirmed to be working](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1265544/comments/113).

#### Question

Since then I haven't dared to update anything related to "Ubuntu Base" in fear that it would replace my nightly kernel with the default, ruining the graphics again. However, a lot of updates have piled up so if somebody could tell me what is safe to update and what to avoid I'd be most grateful. Can I for instance just deselect all entries containing the word *kernel*?

Is it a better idea to switch and follow the 3.15 mainline kernels instead [as described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/388337/how-to-automatically-stay-updated-with-the-latest-mainline-kernel)?

[image]

Comment: If you don't use the Ubuntu provided kernel, why not uninstall it? Run `dpkg -l | grep linux-image` to see all installed kernels. Deleting entries with 'kernel' in their names is the worst idea possible.

Comment: Uninstalling the 3.13 kernel sounds like the best idea, didn't think of it. Should I also remove its headers then? Even though these are deep waters for me I had a feeling it was a bad (and tedious!) idea to manually deselect stuff.

Comment: Do I get it right then that you can have multiple kernels installed, update them separately as you like, and they won't interfere with each other? (Expect perhaps in unusual cases.)

Comment: Those are really general broad questions, and I don't want to vouch that no matter what you do, it won't interfere with something else. It might, but so what? Keep a backup and a live CD/USB for emergencies, and don't hesitate to try things.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comments! I'll uninstall the kernel I don't use and stick to the one that works until Ubuntu 14.10 comes out then. At the moment I can't afford any unexpected downtime.