# Problems with Alsa driver installation

Tags: alsa

I'm struggling with trying to install the sound driver from alsa. I'm getting the following error:

```
The file /lib/modules/3.13.0-35-generic/build/include/INCLUDE_VERSION_H does not exist
```

What are my options?

Comment: Simply how can I install the sound driver for kernel 3.13.0-35-generic?

Comment: If you're running Ubuntu, it comes with ALSA preinstalled and uses PulseAudio to interface with it. The drivers for various soundcards are all included in the kernel. Not sure why you're looking to reinstall/install them a different way. Maybe edit and provide more context?

Answer (score 0):

This error message is output by the compilation script of the `alsa-driver` package.

However, the `alsa-driver` package is outdated; ALSA drivers are part of the kernel, and the only way to update the drivers is to update the kernel.

See, for example, [How to automatically stay updated with the latest mainline kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/388337/how-to-automatically-stay-updated-with-the-latest-mainline-kernel)